# Rename "ArrayOf" in WCF REST arrayList object

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, rest

How can I rename the prefix "ArrayOf" in my root? When I send request or get response. The "ArrayOf" is append to my Collection Name.

Approach:

1. I try use CollectionDataContract, set name

   ```
   [DataContract(Name = "Employee", Namespace = "")]
   [CollectionDataContract(Name = "Employees", Namespace = "")]
   ```
2. Set XMLElement,XMLRoot

   ```
   [XmlRoot("Links")]
   [XmlElement]
   ```
3. Use New class to create element

None of above is working mysteriously.

Current return:

```
<ArrayOfEmployee xmlns:i="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Employee>
      <EmployeeIdentifier>123</EmployeeIdentifier> 
      <EmployeeName>Test1</EmployeeName>
      <ProjectName>NE</ProjectName>
    </Employee> 
    <Employee>
      <EmployeeIdentifier>1234</EmployeeIdentifier
      <EmployeeName>Test2</EmployeeName>
      <ProjectName>NE</ProjectName>
    </Employee>
</ArrayOfEmployee>
```

Comment: current return

<ArrayOfEmployee xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Employee>
    <EmployeeIdentifier>123</EmployeeIdentifier>
    <EmployeeName>Test1</EmployeeName>
    <ProjectName>NE</ProjectName>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <EmployeeIdentifier>1234</EmployeeIdentifier>
    <EmployeeName>Test2</EmployeeName>
    <ProjectName>NE</ProjectName>
  </Employee>
</ArrayOfEmployee>

Answer (score 0):

One approach - you might create a wrapper class (Dataontract) for the array of employees, like "Employees" name and that has `List<Employee>`:

```
class Employees
{
    List<Employee> emps {get;set;}
}
```

Another approach - How about if response is JSON, that would be:

```
 [ {/*employee structure goes here*/}, {...}  ]
```

Hope it helps,